# C program to change the files timestamp in linux

Tags: c, linux, datetime, timestamp

I am writing a C program to change the modified timestamp(time and date) of a file in linux. I found the commands to that but I am looking for a way I can do that through a C program. Is there a way I can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For linux try

```c
int utimensat(int dirfd, const char *pathname,
              const struct timespec times[2], int flags);
```

or legacy command

```c
int utime(const char *filename, const struct utimbuf *times);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, through using the `system()` function and `touch` Linux command. From [system() manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) :

> int system(const char *command);
>
> The system() library function uses... that executes the shell command specified in *****command*****

Edit : This updates the timestamp to the **current** time and date.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to use `system()` to update the timestamps

Comment: I find it a straightforward way to go about accomplishing the task. What's a better approach if you might add?

Comment: Instead of launching a shell process to run a command, just use the relevant syscall. The other answer mentions a couple of options.

Comment: it's straightforward but it's also quite expensive in terms of CPU time. Not a wrong answer, but not the most efficient, either. Most applications would benefit from Bo's solution.

Comment: Fair enough, however I don't see the need to downvote. Perhaps OP wants something quick and running without much dipping into ```struct timespec``` and flags.